# SAS to Python - Remote Access to Oracle database

Tags: python, oracle, sas

I understand how to connect remotely to Oracle database in python:

```
import cx_Oracle
connstr = 'Oracle_Username/Oracle_Password@IP_Address:Port/Instance'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
```

However I have SAS scripts and want to mimic the same procedure in Python but am struggling to understand the role of **path** and **schema** in the following SAS script and if it needs to be incorporated into the Python script?

```
libname ora oracle user=oracle-user                      
                   password=oracle-password 
                   path=oracle-path
                   schema=schema-name;
```

I have read through [documentation](http://support.sas.com/kb/37/888.html) but not being familiar with SAS, it is still very vague.

Comment: path is oracle database that you are trying to connect and schema name is the schema  that you want to see in your assigned library. so your ip_address:port/instance goes to path and User schema goes to schema. I have mostly used schema when I connect with a user that has access to multiple schemas and I want to look in a specific one.

Comment: You mean Python to SAS? If so, please adjust title.

Comment: schema is a database concept, not a SAS concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATH=` option specifies the TNS entry for the Oracle database. Get your DBA to translate that for you into the syntax you need to replace the `@IP_Address:Port/Instance` in your connection string.

The value after `USER=` is what you called `Oracle_Username` and the value after `PASSWORD=` is what you called `Oracle_Password`.

The value of the `SCHEMA=` option specifies which schema in Oracle the SAS libref will use. So if the SAS code later references a dataset by the name `ORA.MYTABLE` then it means the table `MYTABLE` in the schema `schema-name`.  In direct Oracle code you could reference that table directly as `schema-name.MYTABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Pathname= is TNS entry configured in Oracle(sever related details are configured here)
Schema= is user schema

If you are able to connect Oracle you can access any table like below

Schema_name.table_name